# Referring to a different table without a code change

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing some testing using `AWS Lambda` and `DynamoDB` and I would like to keep `DynamoDB` table `table1` as it is with all its data intact.

However, I would like to move on to another test with the same code but this time on `table2`.

Is there any way to do this without a code change and deploying it again to Lambda since I have to

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="table1")
```

to

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="table2")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this while creating dynamodb mapper

```
private DynamoDBMapper mapper;

private DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig;

@Value("${assets.table}")
private String tableName;

@Autowired
private AmazonDynamoDB dynamo;

@PostConstruct
public void initialiseTable() {
    mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamo);
    mapperConfig = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(tableName))
            .build();
}
```